# base64 неверное декодирование email аттача

Tags: php, email, base64

Добры день, уже 2 день сижу не могу найти ответа, проблема следующая, есть скрип на php, который генерирует простой xml файл и отправляет его раз в сутки на указанный email, все отлично, но в редких случаях в конце файла наблюдаю мусор:
[image: мусор в прикрепленном файле]

Аттач кодируется:

```
chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
```

Структура сообщения:

```
To: info@xxxxxxxxxx.ru
Subject: 3456546546_2 [WWWWWW]
From: WWWWWW <qqqqqqqqq@xxxxxxxxxx.ru>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="kkkkkxxxxxxxxxx546756769888"
Return-Path: qqqqqqqqq@xxxxxxxxxx.ru
X-Yandex-Forward: e19aeafbaf64096598b0e8697798bbc9



--kkkkkxxxxxxxxxx546756769888
Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

--kkkkkxxxxxxxxxx546756769888
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=st.xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

PD94bWw....
.....Pgo8L21lc3NhZ2U+

kkkkkxxxxxxxxxx546756769888--
```

Если его открыть outlook'ом 2010 и перейти на вкладку файла, то видим тот же мусор:
[image: мусор в аутлуке]

Нашел зависимость, что если заканчивается сообщение на "+" то будет мусор в конце (и в аутлуке и в яндексе одинаковый мусор в конце), если на = или ==, то все отлично (в яндексе скачивается аттач без проблем, в аутлуке просто не открывается).

Прикрепил файл (изменил исходные данные, поэтому мусор будет по другому выглядеть).

Подскажите, что не так, почему не правильно декодируется в почте файл?

PS. если вставить в любой онлайн декодер данные из прикрепленного eml письма, то данные декодируются верно, их же обратно кодирую и их base64 исходники совпадают, получается тут явно дело именно в декодировании

Файл eml для скачивания joxi.ru/BA0bw9ktL5JNmy.eml

Comment: `=` означает "конец" данных. Попробуйте дополнить сообщение знаком `=` если он отсутствует (возможно трёмя `=`)

Comment: Я тоже так думал, понятное дело что "=" дополняет не достающие байты, чтобы длина была кратная 4. Но берем допустим этот base64 http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/05/15/0002/2584/141848/48/1fd5dbca41.jpg

Comment: А на малых обьёмах крякозябры выходят? Может у вас "кодирующий" алгоритм баг даёт? Расшифруйте ручками хвост - поймёте в чём баг. 4*6 бит = 24 бита, т.е. суть алгоритма что каждые 4 символа дают 3 байта. Вам нужно проверить именно 4(3,2) последних "кратных" символа. Если больше нету ставится `=`

Comment: Сейчас проверю. "Может у вас "кодирующий" алгоритм баг даёт?" там стандартный php base64_encode, если бы это было так, то уже бы весь оверфлоу был переполнен, а я часов 5 искал ответы, не нашел.

Comment: Я нахожу странным, что у вас финальный boundary не начинается с "--". По rfc2046 финальный разделитель идентичен остальным, но добавляется "--" в конце как индикатор завершения сообщения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С base64 у вас вроде все в порядке, ничего лишнего нет. Похоже что у вас неправльный boundary, должно быть примерно так:

```
--boundary
1. body-part
--boundary
2. body-part
--boundary
3. body-part
--boundary--
```

Т.е. нужно добавить -- перед последним boundary, того требует стандарт.

```
--kkkkkxxxxxxxxxx546756769888
Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

--kkkkkxxxxxxxxxx546756769888
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=st.xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

PD94bWw....
.....Pgo8L21lc3NhZ2U+

--kkkkkxxxxxxxxxx546756769888--
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, не первый год на php программирую, но таких еще глупых ошибок я не допускал. Сейчас сам до этого дошел: отправил этот же файл сам себе на яндекс почте, и начал сравнивать 2 файла, еще раз огромное спасибо. И все сходиться: если нет конца аттача т.е. == (которые в base64 означает конец кода, помимо дополнения до кратности), то да он берет из boundery   лишнии куски и делает из них мусор. Спасибо!